Count number of rows within a cell in google sheet
I have names in the following format(this is just a representation, I have this for hundreds of rows) and I want to know the count of names

How can I get the count of the number of rows in a cell.
In this example I want a formula that could give me 8
I could not find a formula. Count does not work here since it will give 6

what about duplicates? should they be count in?

Try this out:
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(SPLIT(TOCOL(A1:C3,1),CHAR(10))))


to not count possible duplicates, try:
=INDEX(IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(TRIM(LOWER(TOCOL(SPLIT(TOCOL(A1:C3;1); CHAR(10));1)))));0))


